# Passing navigation parameters in a sequence of pages in Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

What is the best way or best practice to pass parameters in a sequence of pages in Xamarin.Forms? I am currently getting the parameters from the `OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)` override and casting the `INavigationParameters` to `NavigationParameters`.

The problem is that in Android, it returns a invalid cast exception. All the examples I've searched only showed passing parameters to the next page and reading the parameter values.

I want to pass the parameters to the next page, add parameters and pass it again to the next page until the final page where it will be read.

Comment: Can you provide some context. Why are you trying to cast it to NavigationParameters?

Comment: You should read this: https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/passing-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add additional data using

```
void INavigationParameters.Add(string key, object value)
```

without the need to cast anything.

Perhaps the `this[]` indexer being read-only set you on the wrong track.